# Configure SVN on Linux to allow non-authenticated read/write access

Tags: svn

This is Ubuntu 14.

I have left these lines commented in /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf:

```
# AuthType Basic
# AuthName "Subversion Repository"
# AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
```

in the hope that would allow any user to commit and checkout files, but I am getting:

```
$ svn -m "" commit
svn: E000013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E000013: Can't open file '/var/svn/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix my immediate problem:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/svn
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```